Redirección fallida después de un login exitoso en Next.js
Problema de redirección después de un login exitoso en Next.js
Versión de Next.js: 14.2.4
Paquetes instalados en mi entorno de backend: argon2id, express, jsonwebtoken, cookie-parser, cors
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que utiliza Next.js para el frontend y Node.js para el backend. He creado un formulario de login en Next.js, y tras un login exitoso, debería redirigir al usuario a la página de Overview. Sin embargo, la redirección no ocurre como se espera.
Código del manejo del submit del formulario
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Evita la acción por defecto del formulario
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/Auths`, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: State.email,
          password: State.password,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        // Maneja errores de autenticación, como credenciales inválidas
        setError(data.errors);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Maneja errores de red u otros errores
      console.error('Network error:', error);
      toast.error("Error Server Internal");
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


Middleware:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req) {
    const url = req.nextUrl;
    const { pathname } = url;

    // Simulando una verificación de autenticación
    const isAuthenticated = req.cookies.get('access_token')?.value;

    if (!isAuthenticated && pathname === '/Overview') {
        // Redirige a la página de login si no está autenticado
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.nextUrl));
    }

    if (isAuthenticated && pathname === '/') {
        // Redirige a /Overview si el usuario ya está autenticado
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/Overview', req.nextUrl));
    }

    // Permite el acceso si está autenticado o la ruta no requiere autenticación
    return NextResponse.next();
}

// Configuración del matcher para aplicar el middleware solo a ciertas rutas
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/Overview', '/'],
};


en donde esta ubicado el formulario recientemente agrege esto
useEffect(() => {
    // Verificar si status está definido antes de intentar acceder a sus propiedades
    if (status && status === "Authenticated") {
      return router.push("/Overview");
    }
  }, [status, session, router]);


Descripción del problema:
Después de revisar mi código durante un buen rato, descubrí que al eliminar el middleware, la redirección funciona correctamente. Esto me lleva a pensar que el problema podría estar relacionado con el middleware.
Pregunta:
¿Alguien puede orientarme sobre por qué la redirección falla cuando el middleware está activo? ¿Qué podría estar causando este comportamiento y cómo podría solucionarlo para mantener la funcionalidad del middleware sin romper la redirección?

Hola John, para que la redirección que realizas con NextJS funcione, sería necesario navegar a esa URL. En cambio vos estas haciendo una llamada AJAX y esperando una respuesta, si la respuesta da ok, entonces tu código no redirecciona. En otras palabras, desde NextJS necesitas devolver una respuesta  para analizarla, no hacer una redirección.

Hola Marcos gracias por tu comentario, vale ya que debo devolver la respuesta, pero la cosa es devolver la respuesta al servidor? o que debo hacer especificamente aqui

El middleware que tenes ahora te va a servir para evitar que naveguen directamente a /Overview, pero no te sirve para la llamada AJAX a /Auths.

entiendo. es justo lo que busco hacer que no navegen a /Overview sin estar autenticado. actualize el post, lo que agrege recientemente en el LogIn fue eso, y quite el middleware, ahora que puedo hacer para evitar que los usuarios vayan a /Overview sin autenticar
